# Как обрезать полное ФИО до инициалов в с++

Tags: c++

В программе предусмотрен ввод ФИО. Я не знаю как реализовать, так, что бы вводилось иванов иван иванович, а на выходе получалось Иванов И.И.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста с помощью каких функций можно это реализовать. Или может кто сталкивался с такой задачей и у него уже есть готовый код программы.

Comment: У вас есть пример кода, где вы не знаете как реализовать?

Comment: Нет, даже не имею представления

Comment: Нужно сделать сплит по пробелу и обрезать имя и отчество до первого символа

Comment: Чтобы предоставить готовый код, надо знать какие строковые типы Вы используете.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, как Вы запомнили эти данные. Если у Вас в трех разных массивах (строк, конечно же) лежат ФИО, то ты сначала выводишь массив фамилии, затем по первой букве других массивов. Если же в одном массиве (опять строк) лежит ФИО, то можно различать разные слова при помощи пробелов.
Если вам нужен код, то вот вариант, если у нас массив строк:

```
int main()
    {
    char str[100];
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << ' ' << str[i+1] << ". ";
    for (i++; str[i] != ' '; i++);
    cout << str[i + 1] << '.';
    return 0;
}
```

Если Вам нужно работать со string, то вот код:

```
int main() 
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << ' ' << str[i+1] << ". ";
    for (i++; str[i] != ' '; i++);
    cout << str[i + 1] << '.';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал первый пример. Тот, что с переменной типом char. Ввожу Плысенко Максим Владимирович, а по исходу выводит Плысенко М.М.
Так понимаю второй раз печатает так же имя. Так же во втором цикле for не хватает аргумента. Может в этом дело?

Comment: Да, в этом было дело. Вообще for можно описать и так: for(;;) и будет работать. В прошлом примере я забыл увеличить i. Получалось, что эта переменная находилась в том же месте и ударялась об этот же пробел

Comment: Еще один момент. Как перевести первый символ фамилии и инициалы автоматически в верхний регистр . плЫСенко Максим владимирович. на исходе получить Плысенко М. В.

Comment: Можно поиграться с toupper() и tolower(). Они принимают int и возвращают тоже int, но это не должно Вас волновать, т.к. можно сделать char(), получиться, например, char(toupper(str[i]));